# How can I get a URL to work, if the controller or action name and the URL cannot be the same?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, routes

If the URL is http://example.com/apple-orange the controller or action should be named **AppleOrange** because, by convention, controller or action name is a C# or VB function; so there cannot be dashes right?

So I have to add a route on top the default generic ones:

`routes.MapRoute("AO","apple-orange", new { controller = "Home", action = "AppleOrange", id = UrlParameter.Optional });`

Now, going by this, I need to have a route mapping for every URL whose name has dashes, or for some reason cannot be the same string as the controller or action name.

Is this true? Is there another way to do this without having a separate mapping for each one of those URLs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using the [ActionName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionnameattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[ActionName("apple-orange")]
public ActionResult AppleOrange()
{
    ...
}
```